# Complete and fill data.frame with multiple conditions

Tags: r, dataframe, fill

I want to complete a `data.frame` with all combinations of two variables but with two conditions.
Here is my `data.frame`:

```
Data <- 
  data.frame(
    A = rep(c("a", "b", "c", "d"), each = 2),
    N = 1,
    Type = c("i", "i", "I", "i", "i", "i", "I", "I")
  )
> Data
  A N Type
1 a 1    i
2 a 1    i
3 b 1    I
4 b 1    i
5 c 1    i
6 c 1    i
7 d 1    I
8 d 1    I
```

Now I want to complete that `data.frame` with all combinations of `A` and `Type`, but only if `A != "a"` and `Type == "I"`. So there only has to be one additional row, the row with `A == "c"` and `Type == "I"`. Furthermore, `N` should be filled with `0`, see my desired output below. Is there an elegant way to achieve this? It would be great with `tidyr`'s `complete` but it's OK if not. If the order was like here it would be even better.

```
> Data
  A N Type
1 a 1    i
2 a 1    i
3 b 1    I
4 b 1    i
5 c 1    i
6 c 1    i
7 c 0    I
8 d 1    I
9 d 1    I
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps, you can try this -

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

Data %>%
  mutate(Type = factor(Type)) %>%
  filter(!A %in% A[Type == "I"], A != 'a') %>%
  complete(A, Type, fill = list(N = 0)) %>%
  bind_rows(Data %>% filter(A %in% A[Type == "I"] | A == 'a')) %>%
  arrange(A, -N)

#  A     Type      N
#  <chr> <chr> <dbl>
#1 a     i         1
#2 a     i         1
#3 b     I         1
#4 b     i         1
#5 c     i         1
#6 c     i         1
#7 c     I         0
#8 d     I         1
#9 d     I         1
```

filter for the combination that you are interested in (`filter(!A %in% A[Type == "I"], A != 'a')`), `complete` those `A` values, bind them to the remaining rows and `arrange`.

Comment: Thank you very much! Indeed, that's the implementation of one of my thoughts that I couldn't realize :)

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this

```
library(tidyverse)

Data <- 
  data.frame(
    A = rep(c("a", "b", "c", "d"), each = 2),
    N = 1,
    Type = c("i", "i", "I", "i", "i", "i", "I", "I")
  )

Data %>%
  bind_rows(
    complete(Data, A, nesting(Type)) %>%
      filter(A != "a" & Type == "I" & is.na(N))  
  ) %>%
  mutate(N = replace_na(N, 0)) %>%
  arrange(A, -N)
```

I filter on `is.na(N)` to ensure i get only "new" rows added.